# Handbrake’s stereo downmixing of an MKV 5.1 audio track results in “Center” being right channel and practically nothing is the left channel

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, handbrake, audio-conversion

So I have successfully used Handbrake (version 1.1.2) to convert many large MKV files into smaller, iOS and macOS compatible video files I can play on my iPhone and MacBook Air for a while without really having any issues until this one specific movie.

When I convert it with Handbrake using default “General” settings of seemingly any type—Fast, Very Fast, HQ or Super HQ—the audio downmixing from 5.1 audio results in weird stereo with essentially all of the audio going to the right channel and the left channel seems to have some channel that is just—for lack of a better term—background remnants. Just enough sound to not be silent but utterly no music or dialogue or anything is really audible.

I can play it on VLC (version 3.0.6) on my MacBook Air and I get the same odd sound through my speakers; heavy right barely anything left. But if I set the audio of VLC to “Headphones”… Wow! It becomes a normal stereo downmix.

What is happening and what can I do to properly downmix this? I hope I can do this in Handbrake, but if not I assume I would have to extract the AC3 out of the MKV, downmix it in some other tool and then toss it back into the MKV?

Details of the audio track here using `ffmpeg -i`:

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default) (forced)
Metadata:
  title           : English
  BPS-eng         : 384000
  DURATION-eng    : 01:36:42.624000000
  NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 181332
  NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 278525952
```

Details of the audio track here using `mkvmerge --identify` is:

```
Track ID 0: video (MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264)
Track ID 1: audio (AC-3)
```

Details of the audio track here using `mkvinfo` is:

```
| + Track
|  + Track number: 2 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 1)
|  + Track UID: 3241101187
|  + Track type: audio
|  + Forced track flag: 1
|  + Codec ID: A_AC3
|  + Default duration: 00:00:00.032000000 (31.250 frames/fields per second for a video track)
|  + Name: English
|  + Audio track
|   + Sampling frequency: 48000
|   + Channels: 6
```

Details of the audio track here using `exiftool` is:

```
Track Number                    : 2
Track Type                      : Audio
Track Forced                    : Yes
Audio Codec ID                  : A_AC3
Default Duration                : 32 ms
Track Name                      : English
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000
Audio Channels                  : 6
```

Comment: I suspect that the input has a non-standard channel layout. When that happens, the demuxer will label it with a standard layout with the same number of channels. When rematrixing to another channel layout, obviously the selected rematrixing will be faulty. Do you know the exact channel layout of the input?

Comment: @Gyan Makes sense. Have no idea what the source layout of the input is, but is there anyway for me to analyze the AC3 from the command line or even live? Wonder if there would be a tool out there that could allow for live down mixing of the input so I can—for example—just check off boxes to see what track is what.

Comment: @Gyan Just posted an answer that reflects the steps I took to fix this. If you know of a cleaner way to do this, please feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the channel mapping, you can just use the [channelmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelmap) filter, skipping the intermediate files.

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -c:v copy -c:s copy -af "channelmap=0|2|1|3|4|5" -c:a ac3 out.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

## The “Center” channel was actually “Right” and visa-versa.

### Swapping them results in a properly balanced, normal sounding AC3 file.

I discovered this [based on Gyan’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1396479/handbrake-s-stereo-downmixing-of-an-mkv-5-1-audio-track-results-in-center-bein?noredirect=1#comment2106218_1396479), I decided I can fix this only by actually breaking out individual mono tracks from the AC3, listening to each, and then reconstructing the AC3 to fix the audio layout. Thus, this discovery and the solution to this mini mess.

That said, all of the steps I outline below worked for me, but if anyone knows a cleaner way to do this in one command, please feel free to post as an answer.  I will give you the glory since this is literally the most elaborate FFmpeg and MKV manipulation I have ever done, so it was a learning process.

First, I used `mkvmerge` to identify which tracks are which in `my_movie.mkv`:

```
mkvmerge --identify my_movie.mkv
```

Knowing that I extracted the AC3 file using FFmpeg to a file named `my_movie.ac3`:

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -map 0:1 -c:a copy my_movie.ac3
```

Then I took that `my_movie.ac3` and exploded it into 6 distinct mono tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.ac3 -map_channel 0.0.0 front_left.wav -map_channel 0.0.2 front_right.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 front_center.wav -map_channel 0.0.3 back_left.wav -map_channel 0.0.4 back_right.wav -map_channel 0.0.5 lfe.wav
```

Then I just recombined those mono tracks into a new AC3 file called `my_movie_fixed.ac3`:

```
ffmpeg -i front_left.wav -i front_right.wav -i front_center.wav -i lfe.wav -i back_left.wav -i back_right.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a][4:a][5:a]amerge=inputs=6[a]" -map "[a]" my_movie_fixed.ac3
```

Then I added the newly created `my_movie_fixed.ac3` to `my_movie.mkv` and called the resulting file `my_movie_fixed.mkv`:

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -i my_movie_fixed.ac3 -map 0 -map 1 -c copy my_movie_fixed.mkv
```

It worked! Sound is great via normal “Stereo” playback in VLC as well as when the  `my_movie_fixed.mkv` was converted via Handbrake.

That said, I also adjusted the metadata specifics for the track and set it as a default audio track using `mkvpropedit` like this:

```
mkvpropedit my_movie_fixed.mkv --edit track:a2 --set name=English --set language=en
```